# How can i group elements that are bound to different data (to be used with forcesimulatoin) in D3 so that I can sort them

Tags: d3.js, force-layout

I try to create a Scatter-Plot that uses forcesimulation to place labels around my data points. This works fine so far (thanks to good help on stackoverflow and some blogs :) ). Here is what it looks like so far ...
[Scatter-Plot so far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFFsV.png)

However, I am now stuck trying to reorder my elements so that the circle, line and text elements of each data point are next to each other on the z-axis.

Meaning from what I have at the moment:

```
<g class="circles">
   <circle dp-1></circle>
   <circle dp-2></circle>
   ...
</g>
<g class="labels">
   <text dp-1></text>
   <text dp-2></text>
   ...
</g>
<g class="links">
   <line dp-1></line>
   <line dp-2></line>
   ...
</g>
```

I want to go to ...

```
<g id="dp-1">
   <circle dp-1></circle>
   <text dp-1></text>
   <line dp-1></line>
</g>
<g id="dp-2">
   <circle dp-2></circle>
   <text dp-2></text>
   <line dp-2></line>
</g>
<g>
...
```

I know how I could do this in a "static" case, without using forcesimulation. However, I am out of ideas how to do this in my case, where I run a force simulation on the labels (nodes) and lines (links) but not on the circles.

How can I achieve this properly in D3? Below are the most important snippets of my code.
The main point where I am stuck is that I use different data arrays for my circles (data) and nodes (forceData). The latter basically is an array twice as long as the data (2 nodes per data point).

And I don't know how, to either

- get D3 to draw a "g" bound to two different data, or
- do the force simulation based on the data array (which would only be half the length the node array has now)

Of course other ideas to solve my problem are also welcome.
Thanks for any ideas and help.

```
/**
* Updates the chart. To be used when the data stayed the same, but is sliced differently (filter, ...)
*/
public update() {
this.svg.select('.dataPoints')
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(this.data,
    function (d: any) { return d.category }
  )
  .join(
    function (enter) {
      // what is to be done with new items ...
      return enter
        .append("circle")
        .style("opacity", 0)
    },
    // function (update) { return update },
  )
  .attr("cx", d => this.xScale()(d.x))
  .attr("cy", d => this.yScale()(d.y))
  .style("fill", d => this.color(d.color))
  .style("stroke-width", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.width)
  .style("stroke-opacity", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.opacity)
  .style("stroke", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.color)
  .transition()
  .duration(this.settings.dataPoints.duration)
  .style('opacity', 1)
  .attr("r", d => this.rScale()(d.r))

if (this.settings.labels.show) {
  this.svg.select(".labels")
    .call(this.labelPlacement)
}

private labelPlacement = (g) => {
// we need to create our node and link array. We need two nodes per datapoint. One for the point
// itself which has a fixed x and y (fx/fy) and one for the label, which will be floating ...
var forceData = {
  'nodes': [],
  'links': [],
};

var myXscale = this.xScale()
var myYscale = this.yScale()

this.data.forEach(function (d, i) {
  // doing the two nodes per datapoint ...
  forceData.nodes.push({
    id: d.category,
    label: d.label,
    fx: myXscale(d.x),
    fy: myYscale(d.y)
  });
  forceData.nodes.push({
    id: d.category,
    label: d.label,
    x: myXscale(d.x),
    y: myYscale(d.y),
    dataX: myXscale(d.x),
    dataY: myYscale(d.y)
  });
  // and also adding a link between the datapoint and its label ...
  forceData.links.push({
    source: i * 2,
    target: i * 2 + 1,
  });
});

// now drawing them labels and links ...
if (this.settings.labels.showLinks) {
  var labelLink = this.svg.select('.label-links')
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(forceData.links, (d: any) => { return (d.source + "-" + d.target) })
    .join("line")
    .attr("stroke", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.color)
    .attr("stroke-width", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.width)
    .attr("opacity", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.opacity)
}

var labelNode = this.svg.select('.labels')
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(forceData.nodes, (d: any) => { return d.id })
  .join("text")
  .text((d, i) => { return i % 2 == 0 ? "" : TextService.textLimit(d.label, this.settings.labels.maxTextLength) })
  .style("fill", this.settings.labels.label.fill)
  .style("font-family", this.settings.labels.label.fontFamily)
  .style("font-size", this.settings.labels.label.fontSize)
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended)
  )

// adding and doing the force simulation ...
if (this.settings.labels.force) {
  d3.forceSimulation(forceData.nodes)
    .alphaTarget(this.settings.labels.alphaTarget)
    .alphaDecay(this.settings.labels.alphaDecay)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(this.settings.labels.chargeStrength))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(forceData.links)
      .distance(this.settings.labels.linkDistance)
      .strength(this.settings.labels.linkStrength))
    .on("tick", ticked);
}
```

Comment: can you post enough code so that we can test your demo etc.? Ideally pose your question as a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) - you could set up a "snippet" here or add a link to a https://codepen.io/ etc. Since D3 is "Data driven documents", I think we at least need to see your data (or a simplified version of it). My first idea would be to merge / transform the data with array methods like map / reduce etc.

Comment: Hi Alex,
thanks for your reply. I feared, that it might be a bit hard to understand what I was asking for. Fortunately I found a way to solve the problem by using an a bit different approach. I'll post it as a separate answer.

Comment: No worries. If you want to see how I would have solved it, I posted my answer now below too. In my answer, I only use ``.append()`` - the way I achieve it is through data merging / grouping and then using d3 in a fairly common way, binding our grouped data to each "g" element we create and then appending into that each shape we want. There is always many ways to solve a problem :) happy you found one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for reading. I have been able to solve the problem after 1 more sleepless night :)

I did skip the "g" elements, as they were not really necessary, trying to get a structure like this:

```
<line dp-1></line>
<circle dp-1></circle>
<line dp-2></line>
<circle dp-2></line>
...
```

Doing this I could use two separate data bindings and data arrays (which is needed to use the force simulation).
To achieve the correcting sorting (line - circle - line - circle - ...) i used "d3.insert" instead of append with a dynamically computed "before" element.
Below are the most important parts of the code. Hope this helps someone eventually.

Regards

```
// Drawing the data ...
public update() {
this.dataPoints
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(this.data,
    function (d: any) { return d.category }
  )
  .join(
    enter => enter.append("circle")
      .style('opacity', 0)
  )
  .call(this.drawData)

if (this.settings.labels.showLinks && this.settings.labels.showLinks) {
  this.dataPoints
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(this.forceData.links)
    .join(
      enter => enter.insert('line', (d, i) => {
        console.log("JOIN", d)
        return document.getElementById('dP_' + d.id)
      })
        // .style('opacity', 0)
    )
    .call(this.drawLabelLine)
}
}


/**
   * Draws the data circles ...
   * @param circle 
*/
  private drawData = (circle) => {
circle
  .attr("id", (d, i) => { return 'dP_' + d.category })
  .attr("class", "dataPoint")
  .style("fill", d => this.color(d.color))
  .style("stroke-width", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.width)
  .style("stroke-opacity", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.opacity)
  .style("stroke", this.settings.dataPoints.stroke.color)
  .transition()
  .duration(this.settings.dataPoints.duration)
  .style('opacity', 1)
  .attr("r", d => this.rScale()(d.r))
  .attr("cx", d => this.xScale()(d.x))
  .attr("cy", d => this.yScale()(d.y))
  }

/**
   * draws the lines to connect labels to data points
   * @param g 
   */
private drawLabelLine = (line) => {
line
  .attr("class", "label-link")
  .attr("stroke", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.color)
  .attr("stroke-width", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.width)
  .attr("opacity", this.settings.labels.linkStroke.opacity)
}

// adding and doing the force simulation ...
if (this.settings.labels.force) {
  d3.forceSimulation(forceData.nodes)
    .alphaTarget(this.settings.labels.alphaTarget)
    .alphaDecay(this.settings.labels.alphaDecay)
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(this.settings.labels.chargeStrength))
    .force("link", d3.forceLink(forceData.links)
      .distance(this.settings.labels.linkDistance)
      .strength(this.settings.labels.linkStrength))
    .on("tick", ticked);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include your data, I can give you a high-level conceptual way of solving it on the data side:

Essentially, merging the 3 arrays into one object grouped by the 'color' property (could be any property) using reduce. Then append each circle, line and text into each 'g' element we create for each color.

Note: the `links` array is pointless to have `x1` and `x2` and `y1` and `y2` values as we can get them from the `circles` and `labels` arrays. Also, if possible, you could just define your data like my `combinedData` from the start.

```js
const circles = [
  {shape: "circle", color: "green", x: 2, y: 2, r: 0.5},
  {shape: "circle", color: "blue", x: 4, y: 4, r: 1},
  {shape: "circle", color: "red", x: 8, y: 8, r: 1.5},
];
const links = [
  {shape: "line", color: "green", x1: 2, y1: 2, x2: 1, y2: 1},
  {shape: "line", color: "blue", x1: 4, y1: 4, x2: 2, y2: 6},
  {shape: "line", color: "red", x1: 8, y1: 8, x2: 9, y2: 4},
];
const labels = [
  {shape: "text", color: "green", x: 1, y: 1, text: "A"},
  {shape: "text", color: "blue", x: 2, y: 6, text: "B"},
  {shape: "text", color: "red", x: 9, y: 4, text: "C"},
];

const combinedData = [...circles, ...links, ...labels].reduce((aggObj, item) => {
  
  if (!aggObj[item.color]) aggObj[item.color] = {};
  
  aggObj[item.color][item.shape] = item;
  
  return aggObj;
}, {});

//console.log(combinedData);

const groups = d3.select('svg').selectAll('g')
  .data(Object.entries(combinedData))
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .attr('class', ([k,v]) => k);
  
groups  
    .append('circle')
    .attr('fill', ([k,v]) => v.circle.color)
    .attr('r', ([k,v]) => v.circle.r)
    .attr('cx', ([k,v]) => v.circle.x)
    .attr('cy', ([k,v]) => v.circle.y)
    
groups  
    .append('line')
    .attr('stroke', ([k,v]) => v.line.color)
    .attr('stroke-width', 0.1)
    .attr('x1', ([k,v]) => v.line.x1)
    .attr('y1', ([k,v]) => v.line.y1) 
    .attr('x2', ([k,v]) => v.line.x2)
    .attr('y2', ([k,v]) => v.line.y2)     
    
groups  
    .append('rect')
    .attr('fill', "#cfcfcf")
    .attr('x', ([k,v]) => v.text.x - 0.6)
    .attr('y', ([k,v]) => v.text.y - 0.6)
    .attr('width', 1.1)
    .attr('height', 1.1)
    
groups  
    .append('text')
    .attr('alignment-baseline', "middle")
    .attr('text-anchor', "middle")
    .attr('fill', ([k,v]) => v.text.color)
    .attr('font-size', 1)
    .attr('x', ([k,v]) => v.text.x)
    .attr('y', ([k,v]) => v.text.y)
    .text(([k,v]) => v.text.text)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="100%" viewbox="0 0 12 12">

</svg>
```

Elements in groups:

[image]

Expanded:

```html
<svg width="100%" viewBox="0 0 12 12">
  <g class="green">
    <circle fill="green" r="0.5" cx="2" cy="2"></circle>
    <line stroke="green" stroke-width="0.1" x1="2" y1="2" x2="1" y2="1"></line>
    <rect fill="#cfcfcf" x="0.4" y="0.4" width="1.1" height="1.1"></rect>
    <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="green" font-size="1" x="1" y="1">A</text>
  </g>
  <g class="blue">
    <circle fill="blue" r="1" cx="4" cy="4"></circle>
    <line stroke="blue" stroke-width="0.1" x1="4" y1="4" x2="2" y2="6"></line>
    <rect fill="#cfcfcf" x="1.4" y="5.4" width="1.1" height="1.1"></rect>
    <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="blue" font-size="1" x="2" y="6">B</text>
  </g>
  <g class="red">
    <circle fill="red" r="1.5" cx="8" cy="8"></circle>
    <line stroke="red" stroke-width="0.1" x1="8" y1="8" x2="9" y2="4"></line>
    <rect fill="#cfcfcf" x="8.4" y="3.4" width="1.1" height="1.1"></rect>
    <text alignment-baseline="middle" text-anchor="middle" fill="red" font-size="1" x="9" y="4">C</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Output (crude example):

[image]